# In D3, why is setting a linear scale as a value equivalent to using an anonymous function, in which the scale is applied, to return the value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking at [Mike Bostock's horizontal bar chart example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/), and am a little confused. Everything is pretty simple at first:

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

But, when I get to the second to last block of code, where the rectangles are appended, I can't understand why he used `.attr("width", x)` to set the width value rather than `.attr("width", function(d){return x(d);})`

What, exactly, is going on here? I thought that you needed to supply the x scale with an argument, but this doesn't happen. FWIW, I ran both lines of code through, and got the exact same result — I just can't figure out why this is the case; how does this happen under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested reading:

https://github.com/raganwald-deprecated/homoiconic/blob/master/2012/01/captain-obvious-on-javascript.md

And also:

http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/166

FYI, You just have to check the parameters passed to `x` remember that doing `.attr('width', x)` will call `x` with the datum itself [**AND the index**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr), if `x` doesn't do anything with the index then you're good to go :)

Comment: That's perfect Mauricio, thanks for all those links!

Answer (score 0):

In this example `x` is a function which is simply passed by reference. By using `.attr("width", function(d){return x(d);})` you are just wrapping `x` into another function, which doesn't add anything to your program.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on this: in the latter case, an argument is passed; in the former, how does function use the dataset sequentially as input? I'm confused, because from what I can remember of Scott Murray's tutorials, he always stuck to the `.attr("width", function(d){return x(d);})` format, rather than the one used by Mike Bostock above.

Answer (score -1):

`x` is a function that expect an argument an return an scaled result. D3 sends the data item as argument and this is the magic.

Comment: Yup, I know this, but I'm still unclear on how the array is passed to the scale function as an argument here — it seems like it isn't in Mike Bostock's version of the code.

Comment: It is just in the same way that it passes to your function.